# Routing simplifying url path

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Description

I have a server turning at localhost:8888 . I noticed it is really easy to handle the url string (and simplified even further with the [Path module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) ):

```
                       url.parse(string).query
                                           |
           url.parse(string).pathname      |
                       |                   |
                       |                   |
                     ------ -------------------
http://localhost:8888/start?foo=bar&hello=world
                                ---       -----
                                 |          |
                                 |          |
        querystring.parse(string)["foo"]    |
                                            |
                   querystring.parse(string)["hello"]
```

**For example:**

I have a client that requests an html page. I send it as a response. The client then notices a `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>` and requests the jquery file.

### Question

What is stopping me from putting `src="jquery.js"` ( *localhost:8888/jquery.js* instead of *localhost:8888/js/jquery.js* ) and handling the actual location depending on the file type? Since I know it's it's a `.js` I can just look in my js folder and send it as a response. Would this be considered a bad practice? Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: *"What is stopping me from putting src="jquery.js"...and handling the actual location depending on the file type?"* Nothing. *"Would this be considered a bad practice?"* That's entirely up to you and your team.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder would there be any eventual drawbacks? I completed the coding part in node and it's working fine atm.